# Perl can't locate inline C module: "Had problems bootstrapping Inline module"

Tags: c, linux, perl, inline

Getting the error at the below when trying to run a Perl script. The script is from this package: https://github.com/aquaskyline/LRSIM

```
$ perl simulateLinkedReads.pl
Had problems bootstrapping Inline module 'simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e0722f'

Can't locate loadable object for module simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e0722f in @INC (@INC contains: [some long path]/_Inline/lib /home/olavur/perl5/lib/perl5/5.22.1/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/olavur/perl5/lib/perl5/5.22.1 /home/olavur/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/olavur/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Inline.pm line 541.


at simulateLinkedReads.pl line 0.
INIT failed--call queue aborted.
```

So it's looking for the `simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e0722f` "inline" module, and it seems to be located here:

`[some long path]/_Inline/lib/auto/simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e0722f/simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e0722f.inl`

And the @INC path contains `[some long path]/_Inline/lib`. Should it not contain `[some long path]/_Inline/lib/auto`?

So, I don't know whether the error is from my Perl setup, my installation/build of the `LRSIM` package, or an error in the source code of `LRSIM`.

I'm a complete dummy with Perl, but I tried to include some information about my Perl setup, here (note there are two files, "Perl modules" and "Perl configuration"):
https://gist.github.com/olavurmortensen/00b2baa61399a5b7c39bca323dbf0233

Using `perl -V` for some configuration info and `perl -e 'print qx/find $_ -name "*.pm"/ foreach ( @INC );'` for installed modules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

By suggestion of @melpomene, I ran `strace -f -o trace.log perl LRSIM/simulateLinkedReads.pl` and uploaded the trace here:

https://gist.github.com/olavurmortensen/eca66135486899beccf8610667241451

**EDIT:**

Updated trace, because it was incomplete:
https://gist.github.com/olavurmortensen/eca66135486899beccf8610667241451

Comment: Is there a C compiler installed on your system?

Comment: @melpomene Yes, `gcc v5.4.0` is installed and was used to build the `LRSIM` package.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just run `strace -f -o trace.log perl simulateLinkedReads.pl` and look at `trace.log` to see what's going on.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the complete file.

Comment: It seems to try and fail multiple times to locate an `.so` file: `672   stat("/mnt/fargen/experiments/joint_call/tests/simulate_testdata/LRSIM/_Inline/lib/auto/simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e07/simulateLinkedReads_pl_4e07.so", 0x199b298) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or d
irectory)`

Comment: @melpomene You were right, I updated the trace log, now should be complete.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the error you describe: I was able to install `LRSIM` on my laptop now (according to the instruction on the GitHub page). I then ran `perl simulateLinkedReads.pl` and got no errors. Instead, I got a usage message (which I suppose indicates that it works ok). I am using a threaded Perl version 5.30 on Ubuntu 19.04. (I had [this](https://github.com/aquaskyline/LRSIM/issues/22) issue when running `sh make.sh`, but that was fixed by adding `-fPIC` to CCFLAGS)

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland, this means Perl is not setup correctly on my machine, most likely the `Inline` module is broken.

Comment: Around line 24093 `make` says something about `Clock skew detected`. Maybe the issue is related to the file system the script is running on (`/mnt/fargen/experiments/...`)?

Comment: @melpomene You hit the nail on the head! I was running on a network storage, the Dell EMC Isilon. Using the file system that's physically placed on the machine fixed the problem. If you add an answer to the question I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around line 24093 of your `strace` log `make` says something about `Clock skew detected`. Maybe the issue is related to the file system the script is running on (`/mnt/fargen/experiments/...`)?

`make` relies on accurate time stamps to determine which files need to be updated and to schedule its actions. If the time stamps are wrong, files might be built incorrectly or not at all.

---

The reason `make` is involved at all is because behind the scenes `Inline::C` extracts the embedded C code and creates an ad-hoc Perl module for it, including an XS file, `Makefile.PL`, and the whole machinery. Then it invokes `perl Makefile.PL && make && make install`, which is supposed to create a `.so` file and copy it in a location where perl can load it (this `.so` file is the *loadable object* mentioned in the error message).

Comment: Thanks @melpomene. When I clone and make the `LRSIM` package in my home folder (so on the machine's own storage), and run it from the network storage mounted on `/mnt`, everything works as it should.